# Fetching Json Data but cant load

Tags: android, json, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I can fetch my Json data But i cant load in RecyclerView. I used Logcat to check whether the data is fetched or not .i can see the Json data.
My code are provided below.

Category.java

```
public class Category extends AppCompatActivity {
    public  List<String> Category;
    public RecyclerView rcv;
    public ImageView img;
    public List<CategoryList> items;
    public List<String> Images;

public CategoryAdapter cartAdapter;
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_category);
        Category = new ArrayList<>();
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        Images=new ArrayList<>();


    rcv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Img);
    CategoryAdapter cartAdapter;
    cartAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(Category.this, items);
    rcv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Category.this));
    rcv.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
    new getCart().execute();
    }
private class getCart extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(Category.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }
    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("http://www.dazecorp.com/demos/Vellore_Kitchen/API/CategoryApi.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("request", "Category");
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            Log.d("result", result);


            String error = jsonObject.optString("error");
            if (error.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                JSONArray carts = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Details");

                for (int i = 0; i < carts.length(); i++)
                {

                    JSONObject object = carts.optJSONObject(i);

                    Log.d("object", object.toString());

                    Category.set(i, object.optString("Category"));
                    Images.set(i, object.optString("CategoryImage"));

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < Category.size(); i++) {
                    CategoryList item = new CategoryList(Category.get(i),Images.get(i));
                    items.add(item);
                    Log.d("items",items.toString());
                }

                cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

CategoryAdapter.java

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<CategoryList> items;
CategoryList current;
int currentPos=0;

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView CategoryName;
    ImageView CategoryImage;


    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        CategoryName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        CategoryImage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Img);
    }

}

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryList> items){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.items=items;
}

// Inflate the layout when viewholder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    CategoryList current=items.get(position);
    myHolder.CategoryName.setText(current.getCategory());

    // load image into imageview using glide
    Glide.with(context).load("http://www.dazecorp.com/demos/Vellore_Kitchen/API/CategoryApi.php" + current.getCategoryImage())
            .into(myHolder.CategoryImage);

}

// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null!= items ? items.size():0);
}
```

}

CategoryList.java

```
public class CategoryList {
public String Category;
public String CategoryImage;


public CategoryList(String Category,String CategoryImage)
{
    this.Category=Category;

    this.CategoryImage=CategoryImage;
}
public String getCategory()
{
    return Category;
}
public void setCategory(String Category)
{
    this.Category=Category;
}
public String getCategoryImage()
{
    return CategoryImage;
}
public void setCategoryImage(String CategoryImage)
{
    this.CategoryImage=CategoryImage;
}

}
```

content_category.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_category"
    tools:context="com.example.yuvaraj.vellorekitchen.Category">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

category_list.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp
       "
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/Img"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the onPostExecute(), the result is String, need to convert to JSONObject before doing any processing.

   ```
   try {
       jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   String error = jsonObject.optString("error");
   ```
2. There is no json object "error", so do not check for error in onPostExecute()
   either comment the check.

   ```
   //if (error.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
   ```
3. There is no jasonArray "Details" in response, it is "details" (small letter d). so change it to details

   ```
   JSONArray carts = jsonObject.optJSONArray("details");
   ```
4. Then error msg->java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at

   ```
   Category.set(i, object.optString("Category"));
   Images.set(i, object.optString("CategoryImage"));
   ```

because there is no element added before. So change it to add.

```
Category.add(i, object.optString("Category"));
Images.add(i, object.optString("CategoryImage"));

//Category.set(i, object.optString("Category"));
//Images.set(i, object.optString("CategoryImage"));
```

5. Then java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method notifyDataSetChanged() on a null object reference at cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. This is because global CategoryAdapter cartAdapter; is not initialised, as there is another local decaration in onCreate(), which has local scope. So comment local declaration in onCreate()

   ```
   //CategoryAdapter cartAdapter;
   ```

Comment: @AbYuvaRaj please provide details, what the issue ? you can use the modified adapter class from your your another post.